# Debug Dockerized Flask app in VSCode not breaking on breakpoints

Tags: docker, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I followed this [tutorial](https://blog.hell-io.dev/how-to-debug-dockerized-flask-in-vscode-the-5-minute-guide) to set up debug in my VSCode.

My `launch.json` file is below.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5678
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/server/project/views",
                    "remoteRoot": "/server/project/views"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My code does break on raised and user uncaught exceptions but it does not break on the breakpoints that I set. The code is reaching the breakpoints and I checked it using print statements, but my breakpoints are not working. VSCode debugger does seem to listen to my docker app (seen in the logs in screenshot) but not sure why it is not breaking at my breakpoints. However, it does give an error saying:

> pydev debugger: unable to find translation for:
> "/home/vvarma9/DTNetworkRepos/ip2m-metrr/server/project/utils/assessments.py"
> in ["/home/vvarma9/DTNetworkRepos/ip2m-metrr/server/project/views/",
> "/home/vvarma9/DTNetworkRepos/ip2m-metrr/server/project/views"]
> (please revise your path mappings).

Kindly help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your local and remote paths are correct. You can check your remote path by logging into the container's terminal. There you can find the absolute path of your "app".

I also cannot tell where you `${workspaceFolder}` is actually is. Could be `DTNetworkRepos` or `ip2m-metrr`. You will need to make sure you clarify the path.

Also it would help if you posted up your folder stucture, Docker file for the `server` project and docker compose for all your container projects. Docker file will explain your path on the remote server. Dockerfile & Docker-compose file will ensure us that you have the right cmd or entrypoint for your environment. It may not line up with the tutorial that you set up.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a solution for everyone but in my case, my debugger wasn't stopping on breakpoints due to `pytest-cov` configuration in `setup.cfg`.
I had this in my `setup.cfg`:

```
[tool:pytest]
-addopts = --cov=extension_service --cov-report html --cov-report term
```

Removing the `-addopts` solved my issue.